# Amazon API to get price of products

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, amazon-web-services

i am new to the amazon api, and i have signed up to amazon, but still i don't know how the API works, because of its vast documentation. I need a specific code in php or just angular js or simple javascript, to make me able retrieve the prices of products by entering the ISBN or name of the product through an HTML form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Amazon Product API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) has a function called [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) that can retrieve information based on ISBN.

The [Sample Code & Libraries](https://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API) pages has some (rather old) sample code you could peruse.